# Insert values into the database

Tags: sql, qt, qtsql

I have a table test with three columns ID,value and value_sim. I want to insert values to the value_sim column. I have written the following code but I am getting an error.

```
qry1->prepare("INSERT INTO TEST (VALUE_SIM)"
              "VALUES (:VALUE_SIM)"
              "where ID = 326");
qry1->bindValue(":VALUE_SIM", hxt_val_ft04);
qry1->exec();
```

`hxt_val_ft04` is a float variable which has a value stored in it.

The following error is then raised:

```
Error: QODBC Result :: exec: Unable to execute statement: "[Microsoft] [SQL Native Client] [SQL Server] Incorrect syntax near the keyword WHERE [Microsoft] [SQL Native Client] [SQL Server] Statement (s). (s) could not be prepared. "
```

Kindly help me in correcting the error.

Comment: Have you tried to execute this query directly on db?

Comment: No I haven´t tried it

Comment: Please, try it, in order to find out whether it is a SQL error, or qt/c++ error.

Comment: I agree with @Amartel.  Using some kind of SQL editor / db management studio is invaluable when doing database projects.  Develop and test your SQL before using it in Qt/C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a syntax error in your query, you cannot use WHERE in an INSERT statement, just try to remove this where condition:

```
qry1->prepare("INSERT INTO TEST (value_sim) VALUES (:VALUE_SIM);");
qry1->bindValue(":VALUE_SIM",hxt_val_ft04);
qry1->exec();
```

or you may want to write an update query:

```
qry1->prepare("UPDATE TEST SET value_sim = :VALUE_SIM WHERE ID = 326;");
qry1->bindValue(":VALUE_SIM",hxt_val_ft04);
qry1->exec();
```

**Edit:** For other's may interesting in the final solution:
"casting the value to float solves the problem"

```
qry1->bindValue(":VALUE_SIM", (float)hxt_val_ft04);
```

Comment: I changed it to the UPDATE command which u have specified above but I get an error again.

ERROR: 
QODBCResult :: exec: Unable to execute statement:. "[Microsoft] [SQL Native Client] [SQL Server] Incorrect syntax near 'ID' [Microsoft] [SQL Native Client] [SQL Server] Statement (s) could (n) not to be prepared. "

Comment: I have corrected the syntax error. But I get a new error again.
ERROR : QODBCResult :: exec: Unable to execute statement: "[Microsoft] [SQL Native Client] [SQL Server] Operand type collision: varbinary is incompatible with real [Microsoft] [SQL Native Client] [SQL Server] Statement (s) could (n) are not prepared. "

Comment: i have tested it with a mysql server, i get two different values in the query, double version --> UPDATE TEST SET value_sim = '1.23000000000000000e+000' WHERE ID = 326;
cast to float version --> UPDATE TEST SET value_sim = '1.23' WHERE ID = 326;

perhaps you can try casting to a double and look what happened:
qry1->bindValue(":VALUE_SIM", (double)hxt_val_ft04);
edit: of course i mean the oposite, i should read more carefully your question...

Comment: you could try executing the query without prepare and look what happened:
qry1->exec("UPDATE TEST SET value_sim = " + QString::number(hxt_val_ft04) + " WHERE ID = 326;");

Comment: @HarishRamamurthy: You're welcome, i have updated my answer with this final solution :-)

Comment: Actually I have used the one with casting and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a SQL syntax error for me. Not sure how WHERE condition is used with Insert statement.

```
-- Example:
insert into test(value)values (1) -- Correct 
insert into test(value)values (1) where id = 1  -- Error
```

Comment: Thank you I corrected the syntax but I get this error again. 
ERROR : QODBCResult :: exec: Unable to execute statement: "[Microsoft] [SQL Native Client] [SQL Server] Operand type collision: varbinary is incompatible with real [Microsoft] [SQL Native Client] [SQL Server] Statement (s) could (n) are not prepared. "